# referenced libraries file

Tags: c#, .net, reference

I was wondering where are the referenced libraries actually referenced for `C#`. Why you might ask? Well I am using `Sublime Text 3` instead of IDEs and I would like to keep using `Sublime`. But now I need to use `BigInteger` and I stumbled, because I can't currently link `System.Numerics` to my source. So there must be some sort of config file that I can edit to include libraries.

Comment: Are you just asking where in the hard drive the framework would have installed various assemblies?

Comment: It might make sense to use Visual Studio for setting up your projects, adding new files, doing builds, etc. and use Sublime Text strictly for editing existing files.  I imagine it would be a lot of work to use msbuild "manually."  But I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

The referenced libraries are passed to the C# compiler csc, usually as command line arguments. However, you can also use MSBuild (or xbuild on Mono/Linux) and use project files just as Visual Studio does. These project files are XML files which you can edit as plain text and insert the references there. The project file XML format also allows you to specify a hint path where the assembly is currently located so you don't have to copy it all along.

Comment: As usual it was that simple. Thanks!. Now I am compiling and executing my code no problems.

Answer (score 0):

Add the following to ItemGroup in your project (I suggest using a csproj to compile things).

```
<Reference Include="System.Numerics" />
```

You might look at [omnisharp-sublime](https://github.com/OmniSharp/omnisharp-sublime) for more C# helpers.

Comment: Hi Ryszard. Actually I am not using Omnisharp - I am compiling with mono 4.5 in the console. Georg kindly pointed out that all I need to do is reference the lib manually to the compiler and it is working now. But since you seem to know a thing or two Sublime, is there a way to make it highlight things like BigInteger, DateTime and so on. I have tried posting on the Sublime forum about such issues, but it is.. well, not very crowded :). Thanks

Comment: Sublime does not create AST, it's pattern-based highlighting, which makes understanding the concept of type too difficult for it (the same goes for most editors). You can make your own plist with the most frequently used types, but it's unrewarding. The best thing I can suggest that doesn't require much work is using syntax highlighting for c++, because it gives you decent visibility.